# How to raise open file limit - /etc/security/limits.d vs /etc/security/limits.conf

Tags: rhel, ulimit

Using **RHEL7** with **systemd**

Do you have to use a specific file name convention in `/etc/security/limits.d` (besides the file ending in `.conf`)? There is a file in this directory called `20-nproc.conf`. So if I wanted to raise the open file limit for `USER1` how would I name this `.conf` file? Does that first number matter? ie. `20` in the .conf file `20-nproc.conf`

And should I create this `.conf` in `/etc/security/limits.d` directory since `/etc/security/limits.conf` states:

```
Also note that configuration files in /etc/security/limits.d directory,
which are read in alphabetical order, override the settings in this
file in case the domain is the same or more specific.
...
```

Can I create a .conf file called `30-USER1-nofile.conf`

which contains

```
USER1   soft   nofile   6000
USER1   hard   nofile   6000
```

Comment: this sounds like a RHEL specific thing?  I use SUSE/SLES and for that it's just `/etc/security/limits.conf` where you could just do  `USER1 hard nofile 6000` per the comment section detailing the format in the beginning of the limits.conf file.

Comment: Are you using systemd? I was just reading that for systems using systemd you have to specify the open file limit in the service unit file.

Comment: @jes516 that's the setting for a *service*. If you're talking regular user sessions, then use `/etc/security/limits.d` (i.e., `pam_limits`).

Answer (score 6):

The conf files in the directory are ascibetically sorted, and each sourced in order.

The numbering is a convention to ensure that all sorting methods agree, and to make inserting new rules easy when it comes to placement.

Do not, do not, edit the limits.conf file, as this is now error-attracting as it is just a bad policy in general (the reasons for which weren't as obvious back then).

Comment: i was able to change the open file limit starting the process with systemd using `LimitNOFILE=10000` in the `[Service]` section

Comment: That's a fine solution, if a little non-portable.  As long as you're on a system inflicted with systemd, and the systemd folks don't change it, you should be okay.

Comment: Is it [Manager] or [Service] section? It seems to be Manager on CentOS Linux release 7.5

Comment: Alphabetically sorted, but only files ending with `.conf`. And +1 for the advice not to edit limits.conf directly, but drop in files to `/etc/security/limits.d`.

Comment: Yeah.  the `.d` directory has been a paradigm since like EL5, but conversion is an uphill battle.

Answer (score 0):

from trial and error on a fedora32 box, it seems that the drop-in file must be named `*.conf`

Comment: See `man pam_limits`: "By default limits are taken from the /etc/security/limits.conf config file. Then individual *.conf files from the /etc/security/limits.d/ directory are read."

Comment: Notice also that the OP suggested such a filename: `30-USER1-nofile.conf`

Comment: Can you address the rest of the question? "Does that first number matter?"

Comment: in general these drop-in directories (the ones ending in `.d`) are loaded in alphabetical order, hence the numbering; that will matter only if several files try to define the same setting

Comment: "Does that first number matter?"  -> a little:  It dictates the order in which they're read into the parser (search for 'ascibetically' from three years before you asked).  So yeah, important in theory but it's not often a big deal.